# lxml to parse html:wrong result,why

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Here is a strange thing with my code:

```
import lxml.html
myxml='''
<cooperate>
    <job DecreaseHour="1" table="tpa_radio_sum">  
    </job>

    <job DecreaseHour="2" table="tpa_radio_sum">                                
    </job>


    <job DecreaseHour="3" table="tpa_radio_sum">
    </job>
</cooperate>
'''
root=lxml.html.fromstring(myxml)
nodes1=root.xpath('//job[@DecreaseHour="1"]')
nodes2=root.xpath('//job[@table="tpa_radio_sum"]')    
print "nodes1=",nodes1
print "nodes2=",nodes2
```

What I get is:
`nodes1=[]`  and

```
nodes2=[ Element job at 0x1241240,    
 Element job at 0x1362690,     
 Element job at 0x13626c0]
```

Why `nodes1` is  `[]`? It's a so strange thing. Why ?

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using html parser all attributes become lower-case:

```
>>> root.xpath("//job")[0].attrib
{'table': 'tpa_radio_sum', 'decreasehour': '1'}
```

You can use the real xml-parser:

```
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> root = lxml.etree.fromstring(myxml)
>>> root.xpath('job[@DecreaseHour="1"]')
[<Element job at 0x293daa8>]
```